# Launch App from Notification with data

Tags: android

I'm trying to use C2DM to trigger a push notification on my android phone, and have the user click the notification and launch a certain activity in the app.  How can I pass this information along?

Currently I'm doing the following:

```
        String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager 
            = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);

        int icon = R.drawable.notification23;

        Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT | Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;  

        Context appContext = getApplicationContext();
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, RequestDialogActivity.class);          
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        notificationIntent.putExtra(LocationHandler.KEY_ORIGINATOR, number);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

        notification.setLatestEventInfo(appContext, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);

        final int id = 1;

        mNotificationManager.notify(id, notification);
```

I'm trying to store state by calling `putExtra` on the notificationIntent, but the new activity always has a null savedInstanceState Bundle.  How can I pass information along?

Comment: What exactly have you tried and what doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the extras you set in the intent have to be retrieved by the `getIntent().getExtras()` the `savedInsanceState` is more about retrieve the state when the application have been closed by the system and you want to recover the same state that user saw last time.